# How do I create a daemon thread in Windows with c++?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am trying to create a daemon thread in c++ for windows using the native apis, but I cannot seem to find any reference to daemon threads. Does anyone have a link to the documentation relating to this, or is there a different term for this on windows? How do I create a daemon thread on windows in c++?

Comment: What is a *daemon thread* ? (There is such a thing in python, for example, but it's python-specific). Is it the one you don't want to join when you exit? Then just don't join it.

Comment: I thought that the standard definition was that a process should exit only when all daemon threads return.

Comment: For python, it's the reverse: "when all non-daemon threads return". For C on Windows, there's no such distinction in threads themselves (unlike in pthreads, returning from `main` doesn't terminate an application if there are background threads, but `ExitProcess`, `_exit` and `exit` do).

Comment: Yeah, thats my bad, I was remembering the term backwards. How do you create the effect though? You would need to join any non-daemon threads before the main threads exit, but what if those create non-daemon threads?

Comment: If they create non-daemon threads, let them register new threads in the same list you use for joining, and wait for them too -- repeat until no threads left. Maybe it's better to avoid *daemon* threads, that is, maybe you should never `exit`, just return from `main` and let all other threads die when they want (it's up to you to ensure that they know it's time to die).

Comment: In windows (as opposed to pthreads), if you return from main, wont that kill all the other threads?

Comment: "a process should exit only when all daemon threads return" every thread in windows is like that.  a process won't exit until every thread in it are gone unless you explicitly tell it via an api (ExitProcess was mentioned).  i think that is the case for most os?

Comment: @chacham15 I was wrong on return from `main`, it's equivalent to `exit` on Windows. And exactly as in POSIX, `_endthread(0)` in main doesn't kill other threads.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::thread`?

Comment: There are no "non-daemon" *in your understanding* threads in Windows. All threads are daemon threads, and standard API to create a thread is [`_beginthreadex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: I think you are right that explicitly killing the main thread will leave the process running, but this is a bad idea; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, your main thread should either call `ExitProcess` or return from the main() function when the process is ready to exit.  If there are other threads running that should not be terminated, *it is your responsibility to keep track of this and not exit from the main function until those threads are complete*.

In practice, this means that all threads are "daemon threads".

(In principle, no threads are daemon threads; if you explicitly kill the main thread, the process will not exit until all threads have exited.  Unfortunately, this includes threads that Windows created automatically for you, some of which might not ever exit, so this is not a good idea.)